# How to stop repeating of android ViewFlipper slideshow without user interaction?

Tags: android

I have a ViewFlipper set to auto-flip every 5 seconds. Leaving out some of the details, it looks like this and works fine:

```
for (String photo : imgPaths) {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    Bitmap bmp = Utility.decodeFile(new File(photo));
    image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    imageFlipper.addView(image);
}

imageFlipper.setFlipInterval(5000); // 5s intervals
imageFlipper.startFlipping();
```

but,I have to stop this slideshow after view last image and I have not using any user action to stop or start slideshow.Everything should work automatically.
How can I do it?
thanks

Comment: Are you using animations for the ViewFlipper?

Comment: no.I want only slideshow

Comment: If you add In and out animations, then you can stop flipping by implementing animation listener.

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you apply animation (out or in animation) on view switching, you can set listener to the animation. Listen for the end of animation event, and then check to see if the flipper is on the last view. If yes the stop the flipper from flipping further, this will avoid flipper starting the slideshow again.

```
imageFlipper.setFlipInterval(5000); // 5s intervals 

imageFlipper.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left); //use either the default slide animation in sdk or create your own ones
imageFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);   

imageFlipper.getInAnimation().setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() { 

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            int displayedChild = imageFlipper.getDisplayedChild();
            int childCount = imageFlipper.getChildCount();

            if (displayedChild == childCount - 1) {
                imageFlipper.stopFlipping(); 
            } 
        } 
    }); 

imageFlipper.startFlipping();
```